# How do I return an int from EditText and than show that number in Toast?

Tags: android, textbox, numbers, integer, toast

I am a beginner at programming Android, please help with this simple project.
I want an integer to show up in toast, which I write in `textBox`. I do not know what to put in the highlighted part [here](http://postimg.org/image/5hqq6obal/).

Sorry for the link, but I cannot post the picture

Comment: Post the code that you have so far in your question (not a link to a screenshot) and tell us what problem you are having and we can help.

Comment: you need to add string in there

Comment: I want to write a number into textBox, than show up that number in Toast. I non't know exactly what to write in Toast line, where is arrow, but it seems to be myEdit.getText().toString()
After I done the changes I ran the project and it show: Unfortunately, integers has stopped.
It's difficult to screenshot it, because I have 1 reputation score, but I need 10 to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [getText()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html#getText%28%29) method to get the text the user entered.

Change the myEdit declaration to:

```
final EditText myEdit = ... ;
```

and then use:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, myEdit.getText().toString(), ...
```

Comment: It says that: Unfortunately, integers has stopped.

Comment: Are `button1` and `myEdit` present in `activity_main.xml`? And please post the exception stack trace from logcat.

Comment: So here it is.
activity_main.xml:
http://postimg.org/image/g7k7vu3jn/
MainActivity.java:
http://postimg.org/image/i0o1mvzgt/

Comment: Logcat:http://postimg.org/image/619s7c099/

Comment: It works, it has problem with 2 lines, from:
String myEditValue = MyEdit....